# Logical commit for JPA

Tags: java, jpa, entitymanager

I have to two  tables. ActionLog & QueueLog tables ,When user takes any action I am inserting action table & updating few records in queue table.

Now some times when user does any action then only action table is getting inserted & queue table is not getting updated & I don't see any exceptions or errors in the logs.I want add logical commit in place if either of them fails(line 33 & line 43) then everything should be rolled back,Mean it should not insert or update on any of the tables

```
    EntityManager entityManager = null;
    entityManager = EntityManagerUtil.getEntityManager();
    Boolean isdone = false;

    try {

        ActionLog actionLog = new ActionLog();
        TbBamiActionLogPK actionLogPk = new TbBamiActionLogPK();

        entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
        QueueLog QueueLog = entityManager.find(QueueLog.class, refNo,
                LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE);

        actionLogPk.setRefno(refNo);
        Integer currVerStr = Integer.valueOf(QueueLog.getCurrVersion().toString());
        Integer currVer = currVerStr + 1;

        LOG.info("AR-VERSION currVerStr" + currVerStr);
        LOG.info("AR-VERSION currVer" + currVer);

        actionLogPk.setVersion(currVer);
        actionLog.setId(actionLogPk);
        actionLog.setAction(action);
        actionLog.setPrevAssignee(assignedTo);
        actionLog.setPrevAssgneeRole(assignedToRole);
        actionLog.setAssignee(assignedTo);
        actionLog.setAssigneeRole(assignedToRole);
        actionLog.setComments(comments);
        actionLog.setEntryDateTime(new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()));

        // Adding Action Log
        entityManager.persist(actionLog);//line 33
        LOG.debug("Inseted into action log");
        // Updating Queue Log
        QueueLog.setAction(action);

        QueueLog.setStatus("CLOSED");
        LOG.debug("Updating status as closed");
        QueueLog.setExitDateTime(new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()));

        QueueLog.setCurrVersion(BigDecimal.valueOf(currVer));
        entityManager.merge(QueueLog);//line 43

        LOG.debug("Going to do commit");
        entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
        LOG.debug("Commited..");
        isdone = true;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        isdone = false;
        //entityManager.lock(QueueLog.class, LockModeType.NONE);
        LOG.error("ERR_MSG", e);
    } finally {
        // entityManager.lock(QueueLog.class, LockModeType.NONE);
        entityManager.close();
    }
    return isdone;
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Please read my description ,I want to add logical commit.If any one fails everything should be rolled back

Comment: We have transactions for that

Comment: Yes,,Its one common transaction

Comment: So rollback the transaction in `catch` clause... Am I missing something?

Comment: Agreed ,But even though its not updating Queuelog table its not throwing any exception & no errors in Logs also